# Laravel: Modo class not found

Tags: model, laravel-6

All I did:
 1. Created a Model with the command *`php artisan make:model Modo`*
 2. Tried to get all entries from table modos with echo *`Modo::all()`*
I used the following code:
**Router:web.php**

```
Route::get('todos','TodoController@index');
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use app\Modo;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TodoController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('todos.index')->with('modos',Modo::all());
    }
}
```

**Model: Modo.php**

```
    namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Modo extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**The error : pic**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkBbR.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f90JO.png)

please help me out

Answer (score 1):

Change `use app\Modo` to `use App\Modo`